# upgrading to laravel 10, issues with uploaded files to digital ocean spaces/s3

Tags: laravel

I have upgraded from php 7 and laravel 8 to php 8.2 and laravel 10.

I have most things working.

I am now struggling getting the upload to digitalocean spaces(which are S3 compatible)

I was using sociallydev/spaces-api but it is not compatible with these new versions.

I have added the AWS sdk

here is my composer require

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.269",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.15",
    "elic-dev/laravel-site-protection": "^1.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10",
    "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^3.5"
},
```

But i must be missing a step or package.

My php file

```
<?php
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
 use Aws\S3\S3Client;

 function uploadFileToS3($file, $imageName, $folder = "profilepicts", $fileIsContents = false ){


    $client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',
        'endpoint' => 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => $accessKeyId,
            'secret' => $secretKey
        ],
    ]);
}
```

but the Aws\S3\S3Client client is not found

Is there another aws package i am suppose to be loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use native Laravel Storage, it supports s3. You can find instructions in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#s3-driver-configuration

1. add flysystem package

`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0" --with-all-dependencies`

2. add s3 credentials to .env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
AWS_BUCKET=
```

3. upload and download

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.jpg', $contents);
Storage::disk('s3')->get('file.jpg');
```